# Why does this application crash? (Unhandled exception at 0x52B13499 (ucrtbased.dll))

Tags: c++, stack-overflow

Error: Unhandled exception at 0x52B13499 (ucrtbased.dll) in ConsoleApplication1.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000000, 0x00802000).
Line: 8

Code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void doA();

void doB()
{
    std::cout << "In doB()\n";
    doA();
}


void doA()
{
    std::cout << "Starting doA()\n";

    doB();

    std::cout << "Ending doA()\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Starting main()\n";

    doA();

    std::cout << "Ending main()\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The stack has a finite size. If you have two functions endlessly calling each other, you will run out.

Comment: The (call) Stack is a limited resource.

Comment: I'm going to say it -- is this a troll question?  It is obvious why the program crashes, and if you wrote it, you know why it crashes, since it would be very difficult to just randomly write code like this.

Answer (score 3):

Your stack looks like

```
main()
doA()
doB()
doA()
doB()
...
```

ad infinitum. It's called [mutal recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_recursion).

Each call takes up some stack space (at **least** 8 bytes for the return address). Stack size is finite even if in the GB range.

`8 bytes * Inf > finite stack size`

Comment: yes but the question was, why does it crash xD

Comment: @spuqe What do you think should happen when the "stack overflow"s?

Answer (score 1):

As another answer and comments state, you have infinite call sequence, and each call takes up some stack space.

The C++ standard does not talk about stack limits at all, a crash on stack overflow is an implementation detail / implementation limit.

An implementation could have circular stack, in this case it would not crash on stack overflow. But usual implementations have linear stack and an overflow causes SEH exception / POSIX signal that normally terminates the program.

You have Windows implementation, so stack overflow causes `EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW` (that is what means `0xC00000FD` number in your question). If it is not handled, it is a crash. You can handle it in implementation-specific way, like by using `__try ... __except` statement. Note that you also need to call [`_resetstkoflw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/resetstkoflw?view=msvc-160) in this case, or otherwise you won't be able to handle it more than once. Plus you need to compile with `/EHa` to make sure C++ code tolerates SEH exceptions.

Normally you should avoid platform-specific handling of stack overflow, and just avoid infinite or too deep recursive call.

---

Also note that even for finite stack, infinite or too many recursive calls would not always cause stack overflow. If tail call optimization works for every call, the calls would not consume stack space, and will work like (an infinite) loop.